# How can i Download file to local directly from Dropbox API

Tags: php, laravel, dropbox-api

I m using https://github.com/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk this library in my laravel project .From this code this "example.txt" file downloaded in my project directory. But i want to download this "example.txt" file with my browser into browser download folder.

```
    $file = $dropbox->download("/example.txt");
    $contents = $file->getContents();
    $metadata = $file->getMetadata();
    file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/example.txt", $contents);
```

Answer (score 1):

A little use with Google and found it for you.

```
$file = $dropbox->download("/my-logo.png");
//File Contents
$contents = $file->getContents();
//Save file contents to disk
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . "/logo.png", $contents);
//Downloaded File Metadata
$metadata = $file->getMetadata();
//Name
$metadata->getName();
```

link to examples and github:
https://github.com/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk/wiki/Upload-and-Download-Files

Comment: Sorry ,
i guess i couldn't understand u . my code already working on project directory. Its download the file into  my project path. 

But i want to save that file into browser local download directory . Hope u understand

Comment: Sorry, my fail.. Then you need this:
`$file = __DIR__ . "/example.txt";
$size = filesize($file);
header('Content-type: '.mime_content_type($file));
header("Content-length: $size");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
readfile($file);`